# Bomb Lab: I am on the last step of phase 3

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

The code below is the asm code for phase 3

```
8048bb5 <phase_3>:
 8048bb5:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
 8048bb8:   65 a1 14 00 00 00       mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
 8048bbe:   89 44 24 0c             mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
 8048bc2:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 8048bc4:   8d 44 24 08             lea    0x8(%esp),%eax
 8048bc8:   50                      push   %eax
 8048bc9:   8d 44 24 08             lea    0x8(%esp),%eax
 8048bcd:   50                      push   %eax
 8048bce:   68 ef a1 04 08          push   $0x804a1ef
 8048bd3:   ff 74 24 2c             pushl  0x2c(%esp)
 8048bd7:   e8 34 fc ff ff          call   8048810 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
 8048bdc:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8048bdf:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
 8048be2:   7f 05                   jg     8048be9 <phase_3+0x34>
 8048be4:   e8 36 05 00 00          call   804911f <explode_bomb>
 8048be9:   83 7c 24 04 07          cmpl   $0x7,0x4(%esp)
 8048bee:   77 66                   ja     8048c56 <phase_3+0xa1>
 8048bf0:   8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
 8048bf4:   ff 24 85 80 a0 04 08    jmp    *0x804a080(,%eax,4)
 8048bfb:   b8 b6 01 00 00          mov    $0x1b6,%eax
 8048c00:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c07 <phase_3+0x52>
 8048c02:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c07:   2d 3b 03 00 00          sub    $0x33b,%eax
 8048c0c:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c13 <phase_3+0x5e>
 8048c0e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c13:   05 d6 03 00 00          add    $0x3d6,%eax
 8048c18:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c1f <phase_3+0x6a>
 8048c1a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c1f:   2d 29 01 00 00          sub    $0x129,%eax
 8048c24:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c2b <phase_3+0x76>
 8048c26:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c2b:   05 29 01 00 00          add    $0x129,%eax
 8048c30:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c37 <phase_3+0x82>
 8048c32:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c37:   2d 29 01 00 00          sub    $0x129,%eax
 8048c3c:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c43 <phase_3+0x8e>
 8048c3e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c43:   05 29 01 00 00          add    $0x129,%eax
 8048c48:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c4f <phase_3+0x9a>
 8048c4a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c4f:   2d 29 01 00 00          sub    $0x129,%eax
 8048c54:   eb 0a                   jmp    8048c60 <phase_3+0xab>
 8048c56:   e8 c4 04 00 00          call   804911f <explode_bomb>
 8048c5b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c60:   83 7c 24 04 05          cmpl   $0x5,0x4(%esp)
 8048c65:   7f 06                   jg     8048c6d <phase_3+0xb8>
 8048c67:   3b 44 24 08             cmp    0x8(%esp),%eax
 8048c6b:   74 05                   je     8048c72 <phase_3+0xbd>
 8048c6d:   e8 ad 04 00 00          call   804911f <explode_bomb>
 8048c72:   8b 44 24 0c             mov    0xc(%esp),%eax
 8048c76:   65 33 05 14 00 00 00    xor    %gs:0x14,%eax
 8048c7d:   74 05                   je     8048c84 <phase_3+0xcf>
 8048c7f:   e8 0c fb ff ff          call   8048790 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 8048c84:   83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
 8048c87:   c3                      ret
```

Using gdb, i can see that i need to input 2 integers

```
(gdb) x/s 0x804a1ef
0x804a1ef:  "%d %d"
```

From this line, i can that the first argument must be less than 7

```
0x08048be9 <+52>:   cmpl   $0x7,0x4(%esp)
```

This is optimized switch expression

```
 8048bf4:   ff 24 85 80 a0 04 08    jmp    *0x804a080(,%eax,4)
 8048bfb:   b8 b6 01 00 00          mov    $0x1b6,%eax
 8048c00:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c07 <phase_3+0x52>
 8048c02:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c07:   2d 3b 03 00 00          sub    $0x33b,%eax
 8048c0c:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c13 <phase_3+0x5e>
 8048c0e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c13:   05 d6 03 00 00          add    $0x3d6,%eax
 8048c18:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c1f <phase_3+0x6a>
 8048c1a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c1f:   2d 29 01 00 00          sub    $0x129,%eax
 8048c24:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c2b <phase_3+0x76>
 8048c26:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c2b:   05 29 01 00 00          add    $0x129,%eax
 8048c30:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c37 <phase_3+0x82>
 8048c32:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c37:   2d 29 01 00 00          sub    $0x129,%eax
 8048c3c:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c43 <phase_3+0x8e>
 8048c3e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c43:   05 29 01 00 00          add    $0x129,%eax
 8048c48:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c4f <phase_3+0x9a>
 8048c4a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c4f:   2d 29 01 00 00          sub    $0x129,%eax
 8048c54:   eb 0a                   jmp    8048c60 <phase_3+0xab>
 8048c56:   e8 c4 04 00 00          call   804911f <explode_bomb>
 8048c5b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
```

And the i used GDB to inspect the structure:

```
(gdb) x /10a 0x804a080
0x804a080:  0x8048bfb <phase_3+70>  0x8048c02 <phase_3+77>0x8048c0e <phase_3+89>    0x8048c1a <phase_3+101>
0x804a090:  0x8048c26 <phase_3+113> 0x8048c32 <phase_3+125>0x8048c3e <phase_3+137>  0x8048c4a <phase_3+149>
0x804a0a0 <array.3249>: 0xa 0x2
```

I am stuck on this step, if am correct, i have to choose a number arbitarily from 0 to 6 and go through the switch expression to get the second argument.
How am i going to get the second argument?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good job figuring it out! What exactly is your problem with the final step? You have the `switch` entries, just follow whichever one you want. PS: the comparison uses `ja` so your input can be 0 to 7 inclusive. Although later at `8048c60` there is an additional check `cmpl   $0x5,0x4(%esp)`.

Comment: while runing the bomb within gdb, for phase 3, i input "3  15". i got a breakpoint, which i guess means that the first argument can be 3.  So the main problem is finding the exact correct second argument or i will try all switch entries as second arguments to 3 as first arguments, or there is another way

Comment: If you want `3` you only need to run through the 4th `switch` entry (indexing starts with zero). If you are running in gdb, you don't even need to bother, you just put a breakpoint at `8048c67` and the value in `eax` is your expected number.

Comment: the 4th switch is  0x8048c26 <phase_3+113> . And after checking registers at 8048c67 . eax is -297

Comment: Yes, i found that the input integer was 3 -297 and i was able to defuse phase_3. But i still want to understand why i had to put breakpoint at 8048c67

Comment: That's where the comparison happens. `if (calculated_value != input_value) explode_bomb();`. You can just print the `calculated_value` there.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time and effort. I Appreciate that.